# Select where statement returning all null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, null, where-clause

I'm using java to modify the table. after running this code

```
tab=b[i];

myStatement.executeUpdate("UPDATE hetero.temporary SET CatTable = ' "+tab+" ' WHERE CatTable IS NULL");
```

my table is modified

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| '1', 'Achilles Tendon',  ' Bodyparts ', '0'  |
| '2', 'Adenoids',         ' Bodyparts ', '0'  |
| '3', 'Adrenaline',       ' Bodyparts ', '0'  |
| '4', 'Alimentary Canal', ' Bodyparts ', '0'  |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

but using

```
SELECT * 
FROM hetero.temporary
Where Cattable LIKE 'Bodyparts '
```

returns

a row where all the values are null

if it helps im using MySQL Workbench and intellij

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM hetero.temporary WHERE Cattable IS 'Bodyparts '`

Comment: @Spectric, I'd expected syntax error. Use `=` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the value you inserted

```
' Bodyparts '
```

It has a space before and after the text.  When you searched you looked for

```
LIKE 'Bodyparts '
```

Note the lack of a leading space.  Also, since you didn't include any wildcards, the statement is equivalent to

```
= 'Bodyparts '
```

so of course nothing matches.  This would work if you wrote

```
LIKE '%Bodyparts%'
```

but it's not clear that's what you want.  Decide if you really want leading and trailing spaces.

Also, note that building a SQL statement the way you do is open to SQL Injection attacks.  You should be using placeholders, as in

```
"UPDATE hetero.temporary SET CatTable = ? WHERE CatTable IS NULL"
```

And then provide the value at run time using a prepared statement.

Comment: `LIKE` takes trailing spaces into consideration, but `=` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for a while